# javascript property delete if false nothing if true loop

Tags: javascript, loops, object, for-loop, methods

I need to loop through an objects keys and if the property is false then delete the keys property. This is what I have so far but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
function onlyTheTruthy() { 
 onlyTheTruthy.key;
  var prop;

  for (key in onlyTheTruthy){
    if (key != true) {
     delete onlyTheTruthy.key.prop
    }
  else {
       }

  }
  return onlyTheTruthy;

};
```

Comment: firstly: in the for...in loop, key will always be a string, and will always be truthy, secondly, what are you doing wrong depends on what you are trying to achieve, which is not obvious from your code which has several oddities to say the least

Comment: @muhahmad share the structure of object.

Answer (score 0):

In a `for...in` loop, use the `key` to access the value on the object. This is done with brackets like `obj[key]`.

```
function onlyTheTruthy(obj) {

  for (var key in obj) {
    if (!obj[key]) {
      delete obj[key];
    }
  }

  return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function onlyTheTruthy() {
    onlyTheTruthy.key;
    var prop;
    for (key in onlyTheTruthy) {
        if (key != true) {
            delete onlyTheTruthy.key.prop
        } else {}
    }
    return onlyTheTruthy;
};
```

This is your code.

Line:

1. You declare a function named `onlyTheTruthy`, taking no arguments. However, I think it ought to take one: `o`.
2. This line does nothing. It should be removed.
3. You set the scope of the variable `prop`, but give it no value. Fine.
4. A [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop. You may want to research exactly what that does. The `key` variable hasn't been seen before, other than on line 2, but that is a *different variable*: a property of `onlyTheTruthy`. Also, you're looping through the keys of the function you're inside of: `onlyTheTruthy`. I'm confident this isn't what you want. Try:

   ```
   for (prop in o) {
   ```
5. Checking if `key` is not equal to true. Not too often are boolean values used as object keys. Maybe:

   ```
   if (!o[prop]) { // Or, more verbosely:
   if (o[prop] === false) {
   ```
6. Look up [square brackets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) (`[]`).
7. Empty `else`. How about *no* `else`? It's not required, you know.
8. `}` Closing the `for...in` loop.
9. Returning the function itself. Nope. How about `o`? Or, if you end up modifying the object itself, there's no need for a return at all.
10. No semicolon necessary at the end of a function declaration.

Happy Coding!

Fixed version:

```
function onlyTheTruthy (o) {
    for (var prop in o) {
        if (!o[prop])
            delete o[prop];
    }
}
```